# Spatial neighbors to voxels for R-INLA

Tags: r, 3d, nearest-neighbor, spdep

I am working on an fMRI dataset that I want to analyse using a Bayesian spatial model in R-INLA. I extracted the coordinates for all these voxels. (See the image to get an impression one such a subcortical brain volume). My data is in a matrix with approximately 30.000 rows with three columns representing the X, Y, and Z coordinates. What I need to do now, is get the six spatial neighbors per coordinate. (To be specific, the x+1, x-1, y+1, y-1, z+1, z-1).

[image]

As you can see in the picture, there is empty space surrounding the brain volume. I tried knearneigh() from the spdep-package to get the six neighbours, but this did not correctly handle the edge-cases sitting next to the empty space. As expected, it just moved 'deeper into the brain' volume to find neighbors for the places that should be empty. (I hope this description is sufficient). I also tried using dnearneigh(), but this (seemingly) did not handle 3D data formats. Ideally, the software doing this will return an nb file type, that I can then turn into an INLA-graph file type. The empty-neighbors should be represented by NaN's in the file. As a bonus feature, it would be nice if the software was flexible enough to also return (1) more than six neighbors and/or (2) decaying weights as we move further away from the voxel.

I hope someone here is familiar with this. This StackExchange seemed most appropriate for asking my question, since I found threads on INLA and spatial neighbors. Even though I am working on neuroimaging data.

Comment: Could you add six extra "sides" of 1 voxel to your volume, filled with NA values, to make it (N+2)x(M+2)x(P+2). Then compute the six nearest neighbours, for all those voxels, then throw away the data for the neighbours of the six extra sides.

Comment: If you could make a simple example data set (maybe only 5x6x7 voxels) and a description of the output format then it might be easier for someone to write the code to do it...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried implementing something similar. I started by calculating the Euclidean distances between all three-dimensional coordinates, creating a distance matrix. Then I searched through each row for the distances that were equal to one, meaning they are direct neighbors. I am now row-binding all the rows into an empty matrix of dimension (#voxels x 6). I will have to see if this can easily be transformed into an nb-file.

Comment: To do the NaN padding for row-binding at the end, the following function can be used. Altogether, that's how I ended up solving the problem, for future reference: pad  <- function(x, n) {
  len.diff <- n - length(x)
  c(x, rep(NA, len.diff)) 
}